# android changing variables randomly

Tags: android

I have set the following to load, but now I have a 2nd background image that I like to randomly display. How do I go about randomly changing background to background2 back and forth?

Here is what I have:

```
static_background_building = new Sprite(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.background), ScreenWidth());

static_background_building = new Sprite(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.background2), ScreenWidth());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy. Just set a random number between 0 and 1 and set your background accordingly.

```
Random random = new Random();
int number = random.nextInt(2); // Gives a number such that 0 <= number < 2
```

Then:

```
if(number == 0)
   static_background_building = new Sprite(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.background), ScreenWidth());
else
   static_background_building = new Sprite(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.background2), ScreenWidth());
```

Comment: I was wondering if I could do something along the line: R.drawable.background$randnumhere

Comment: You have to import that class. Ctrl+Shift+O will do the job.

Comment: can i do this?Random random = new Random();
  int number = random.nextInt(2); // Gives a number such that 0 <= number < 2
  static_background_building = new Sprite(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.background+random), ScreenWidth());

Comment: You can use `int drawableResourceId = this.getResources().getIdentifier("background"+number, "drawable", this.getPackageName());` to get the resource Id and then use that id when setting the background.

Comment: i tried doing `R.drawable.drawableResourceId` it's giving me an errot

Comment: changed `R.drawable.drawableResourceId` to just `drawableResourceId` works great :)!!! Thank you so much!

Comment: how do I go about re-using `drawableResourceId` a few lines down in a `if(static_background_building=="xxxx")` ? it's telling me `static_background_building` is not a variable...

Comment: I even try to use if with `number` a few hundred lines down and it said `number` is not a variable